# ConversationHandler not working when deployed on Heroku but is working good when running on local machine

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I am using Python Telegram Bot library to make a bot that has a conversation which let's users name their project, payment plans etc. The conversation consists of MessageHandlers and CallBackQueryHandlers. Thr problem I'm facing is, this conversation was working fine when I was using this bot from my local machine, but when I deployed it to heroku, I can't have the full conversation, it would become unresponsive at some point and I would have to cancel the conversation(which surprisingly, works at lightning bolt speed). All other handlers of my application work as expected and respond quickly.

I am using webhook in this application.

The ConversationHandler:

```py
add_project_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(project_name, pattern="add_project")],
        states={
            PROJECT_NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex(".*"), store_name_maybe_project_type)],
            PROJECT_TYPE: [CallbackQueryHandler(store_type_maybe_admin)],
            ADMIN:[CallbackQueryHandler(connect_channel)],
            CONNECT:[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(".*"), connect_channel_add_currency)],
            CURRENCY:[CallbackQueryHandler(store_currency_maybe_frequency)],
            FREQUENCY:[CallbackQueryHandler(store_frequency_maybe_amount)],
            MONEY:[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(".*"), store_amount_maybe_bot)],
            TOKEN:[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(".*"), store_bot_show_links)],
            PAY_SETUP:[CallbackQueryHandler(setup_payment)],
            PAYPAL:[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(".*"), handle_client_id)],
            CLIENT_ID:[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(".*"), handle_client_secret)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )
handlers.append(add_project_handler)
```

EDIT:

So I checked out the logs, and I saw some really weird behavior, so it recieves an update, and right now, the state of the conversation should have been 1, but it says 'selecting conversation with state None'. That too it does three times.

```
2021-10-01T16:55:59.411864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/1967487217:AAGDmzoxPPlB386VuEYr4s8dPM50fr49d84" host=invitememberbot.herokuapp.com request_id=6d10ee36-ebe4-40de-91b3-48c5e33d6172 fwd="91.108.6.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=154 protocol=https
2021-10-01T16:55:59.415201+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-01 16:55:59,414 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - DEBUG - Processing Update: {'callback_query': {'chat_instance': '1523769404808794079', 'id': '4756348607585474313', 'data': 'channel', 'message': {'delete_chat_photo': False, 'chat': {'id': 1107423707, 'first_name': 'Palash', 'type': 'private', 'username': 'raghu_palash', 'last_name': 'Raghuwanshi'}, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'date': 1633106830, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'reply_markup': {'inline_keyboard': [[{'callback_data': 'channel', 'text': 'Paid Telegram Channel'}]]}, 'group_chat_created': False, 'photo': [], 'caption_entities': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'message_id': 2657, 'entities': [], 'text': 'What do you want to make?', 'new_chat_photo': [], 'from': {'id': 1967487217, 'first_name': 'InviteMemberBot', 'username': 'InviteMemberFiverrBot', 'is_bot': True}}, 'from': {'language_code': 'en', 'last_name': 'Raghuwanshi', 'id': 1107423707, 'first_name': 'Palash', 'username': 'raghu_palash', 'is_bot': False}}, 'update_id': 334393256}
2021-10-01T16:55:59.415374+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-01 16:55:59,415 - telegram.ext.conversationhandler - DEBUG - selecting conversation (1107423707, 1107423707) with state None
2021-10-01T16:55:59.415584+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.90.119 - - [01/Oct/2021:16:55:59 +0000] "POST /1967487217:AAGDmzoxPPlB386VuEYr4s8dPM50fr49d84 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-"
2021-10-01T16:55:59.415742+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-01 16:55:59,415 - telegram.ext.conversationhandler - DEBUG - selecting conversation (1107423707, 1107423707) with state None
2021-10-01T16:55:59.415867+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-01 16:55:59,415 - telegram.ext.conversationhandler - DEBUG - selecting conversation (1107423707, 1107423707) with state None
```

And here's something more weird, when I click the button twice rapidly, it takes me to the next state.

```
2021-10-01T17:15:24.421256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/1967487217:AAGDmzoxPPlB386VuEYr4s8dPM50fr49d84" host=invitememberbot.herokuapp.com request_id=ea099aff-e9dd-46fa-8516-958677290171 fwd="91.108.6.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=154 protocol=https
2021-10-01T17:15:24.420031+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-01 17:15:24,419 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - DEBUG - Processing Update: {'callback_query': {'chat_instance': '1523769404808794079', 'id': '4756348606350994438', 'data': 'channel_done', 'message': {'delete_chat_photo': False, 'chat': {'id': 1107423707, 'first_name': 'Palash', 'type': 'private', 'username': 'raghu_palash', 'last_name': 'Raghuwanshi'}, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'date': 1633107558, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'reply_markup': {'inline_keyboard': [[{'callback_data': 'channel_done', 'text': 'Done'}]]}, 'group_chat_created': False, 'photo': [], 'caption_entities': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'message_id': 2659, 'entities': [], 'text': "Please create a private Telegram channel and click Done when it's ready:", 'new_chat_photo': [], 'from': {'id': 1967487217, 
'first_name': 'InviteMemberBot', 'username': 'InviteMemberFiverrBot', 'is_bot': True}}, 'from': {'language_code': 'en', 
'last_name': 'Raghuwanshi', 'id': 1107423707, 'first_name': 'Palash', 'username': 'raghu_palash', 'is_bot': False}}, 'update_id': 334393260}
2021-10-01T17:15:24.420209+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-01 17:15:24,420 - telegram.ext.conversationhandler - DEBUG - selecting conversation (1107423707, 1107423707) with state 1
```

I don't understand why it worked fine when I ran it on my own machine, but does this on heroku.

Additional Information -

These are the functions that are involved in this log:

```py
def store_type_maybe_admin(update, context):
    # Open db connection
    conn = DB_POOL.getconn()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # stores project type and conditonally asks for making admin
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Done", callback_data="channel_done")]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    if query.data != "channel_done":
        context.user_data["project_type"] = query.data
        q = "UPDATE project SET project_type = %s WHERE id = %s"
        cur.execute(q, (query.data, context.user_data["project_id"]))
        conn.commit()
        message = f"Please create a private Telegram {query.data} and click Done when it's ready:"
        video = "BAACAgUAAxkDAAICCGFK8ud7FDZ2qbzOkQfrDId-abgXAAKqAwAC-KBYVquzwMps2x7GIQQ"
        return_value = PROJECT_TYPE
    else:
        message = "Please add this bot (@InviteMemberFiverrBot) to the channel admins. It needs Add Subscribers permission.\n\nPress Done when it's ready:" 
        video = "BAACAgUAAxkDAAICFmFK9GB185nfUvTeE6P3ZTnEp1YEAAKxAwAC-KBYVtfAgpeMwSB0IQQ"
        return_value = ADMIN
    # Send a video
    context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, video=video)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id ,text=message, reply_markup=reply_markup, parse_mode="markdown")

    DB_POOL.putconn(conn)
    return return_value # will be either PROJECT_TYPE = 1 or ADMIN = 2

def connect_channel(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    video = "BAACAgUAAxkDAAICGWFK9ShTxKcIN32o9njkIQMCXcwoAAKyAwAC-KBYVi7hYk0auE7IIQQ"
    context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, video=video)
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
        text=f"To connect the channel, please forward a message (any) from the channel to this bot."
    )
    return CONNECT
```

This is how I have setup my bot:

```py
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
dispatcher = setup(bot, db_pool)

@app.route(f"/{TOKEN}", methods=["POST"])
def respond():
    """Run the bot."""
    update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
    dispatcher.process_update(update)
    return "ok"
```

the setup function:

```py
def setup(bot, db_pool):

    # Create bot, update queue and dispatcher instances
    dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, None, workers=0)

    ##### Register handlers here #####
    initialize_bot_handlers = initialize_bot(db_pool) # initialize_bot returns a list of handlers
    for handler in initialize_bot_handlers:
        dispatcher.add_handler(handler)
    
    return dispatcher
```

The conversation handler is inside the initialize_bot function.

Comment: I recommend to set PTBs log level to debug and check both the heroku log and ptbs logs. BTW, as `Filters.regex(".*")` will just match any text, you might als well just use `Filters.text`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CallMeStag, I have updated the answer after getting the log output, also I have added the information that might be necessary, I would be really grateful if you would help me with this.

Comment: you should revoke the bot token that you published in the logs ;)

Comment: I did it a while ago, thankyou.